# Is it 'PowerApps' or 'Power Apps'?

Tags: powerapps

I am sometimes engaged in content writing and I don't understand the differencce between PowerApps and Power Apps. I see most writers using 'PowerApps' while Microsoft uses 'Power Apps'. Which word is contextually correct?

Comment: Probably off topic here. It's probably trademarked, so I'd look up the trademark application for the official orthography.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It used to be "PowerApps", but it was rebranded to "Power Apps" (with space) earlier this year (probably some marketing decision, I don't know). You'll likely see PowerApps (no space) in all old references, and possible for quite some time until the new name gets to people's minds.

Answer (score 2):

It is "Power Apps" now. You can also verify by visiting  [powerapps.microsoft.com](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/), the official site.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier it was PowerApps, now it is "Power Apps".